# Ignite instance name thread local must be set or this method should be accessed under org.apache.ignite.thread.IgniteThread

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ignite

I am trying to access ignite cache values from spark map operation

[Ignite grid name thread local must be set or this method should be accessed under org.apache.ignite.thread.IgniteThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545956/ignite-grid-name-thread-local-must-be-set-or-this-method-should-be-accessed-unde)

I have exact same problem, and tried some method suggested by the person who asked the same question

```
val cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache[String,String]("newCache")
val cache_value = cache.get("key")
val myTransformedRdd = myRdd.map { x =>println(cache_value)}.take(2)
```

This is my sample code, I understood that, when we initiates ignite(Ignition.start()), it may only initiates in spark driver, but spark executes in executors. So in some executors the ignite may not be initiated.

So I tried this also,

```
val myTransformedRdd = myRdd.map { x =>
   if(Ignition.state.toString=="STOPPED")
    {
     Ignition.start("/etc/ignite/examples/config/example-ignite1.xml")
     }
println(cache_value)
}
```

From this I got the same error.

Comment: Can you share the full code sample that you are going to implement?

Comment: I added , When the cache value is not from ignite it will work fine.  The problem arises when we use the ignite cache values in spark map function. I think the ignite is not started in spark executors, it will start only on driver. Hence I gave the If condition.

Comment: In that ticket Val said that you should avoid sending of ignite instance to executors. So try to replace "ignite.getOrCreateCache[String,String]("newCache")" on next "Ignition.getOrStart("/etc/ignite/examples/config/example-ignite1.xml").getOrCreateCache[String,String]("newCache")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that `ignite` in your sample is taken from the outer scope somewhere, outside the mapper function. Make sure, that you don't try to send this object over the network.

In your example you use `cache_value` taken from the driver's context. Your mapper function should look something like

```scala
val myTransformedRdd = rdd.map { _ =>
  val igniteCfg = Ignition.loadSpringBean("/etc/ignite/examples/config/example-ignite1.xml", "ignite.cfg")
  val ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteCfg)
  val cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache[String,String]("newCache")
  val cacheValue = cache.get("key")
  println(cacheValue)
}
```

Note, that `example-ignite1.xml` file should have a defenition of a `ignite.cfg` bean of type `IgniteConfiguration`.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration
Serialization stack:
 - object not serializable (class: org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration, value: IgniteConfiguration 

Again I got this error

Comment: Hi Denis , I gave igniteCfg inside the map function.And it is worked ! . Can you edit your answer , Then I will accept your answer